# Two variable limit

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus, polar-coordinates

Suppose I have a function which is defined in different parts, for example:

$$f(x,y)=y\cos\left(\frac{x}{y}\right)\ \ \ y\neq0$$
$$f(x,0)=0$$

and I have to calculate the limit when $(x,y)\rightarrow (x_0,0)$.
Is it possible to calculate it separately through the curves $y=0$ and $y\neq 0$ and say that if both are the same, then the limit is that number? I have seen this procedure a number of times, but I have the following doubt: it would be possible to find a curve $C$ with points satisfying both $y=0$ and $y\neq0$, and therefore the division made above does not consider all the curves passing through $(x_0,0)$.

Which is the correct argumentation to solve a limit of this kind?

Comment: No, just checking two curves isn't enough to prove existence, but it might suffice to prove the limit doesn't exist. You can find that this particular limit is $0$ by bounding the absolute value of the function appropriately.

Comment: If the limit exists it can't be different from what you get when taking the limit along any curve, but you can't conclude that it exists just because you get the same limit along different curves.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using:
$$\large-1\le\cos x\le1\\\implies\large-y\le y\cos\frac{x_0}{y}\le +y$$
Think what will happen if $y\to0$

**Spoiler**:Hint:

> Think in terms of Sandwich theorem, maybe the limit is $0$? Is it?

Answer (score 0):

When $(x,y)\rightarrow (x_0,0)$ I have 
$$ 0\leftarrow 0\leq |f(x,y)| \leq \max\{|ycos(\frac{x}{y})|,0\}\leq \max\{|y|,0\} \rightarrow 0 $$
Using the sandiwch rule I have that the limit is 0.

Thank you very much for your help.